# :checked selector not changing desired css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change a wrapper's background color by pressing the checkbox.

```css
.switch_1:checked~.table_wrapper {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="switch_box box_1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch_1">
  </div>
</li>
<div class="table_wrapper">
</div>
```

Comment: `.table_wrapper` isn't a sibling of `.switch` so your selector with `~` won't work. And since there's no parent selector yet, there'd be no way to do this with CSS alone

Comment: The `~` is the general *sibling* selector. So unless your wrapper is a sibling (child of same parent element) of the input, you cannot access it.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, no idea how I've overlooked that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change the DOM structure, you can't do it with CSS but you can do it with JS.

```js
$(".switch_1").change(function () {
$('.table_wrapper').toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.table_wrapper.active {
background: black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="switch_box box_1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch_1">
  </div>
</li>
<div class="table_wrapper">
asd
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what would work. The element needs to be a sibling (side-by-side) for it to work.

There's currently no "parent selector" in css: [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

So I think your best option to deliver the functionality you're working towards would be with javaScript.

```css
.switch_1:checked~.table_wrapper {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="switch_box box_1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="switch_1">
    
    <div class="table_wrapper">hello</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, its working indeed, but I need the div out of the li's.